# Unable to navigate and click on "All" radio button under System TAB since there are multiple radio button with name ALL under Other Tabs in the page

Tags: xpath, radio-button

```
    <div _ngcontent-c15="" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 p-0">
    <div _ngcontent-c15="" class="row">
        <div _ngcontent-c15="" class="col-md-12 p-0 mb-2">
            <h5 _ngcontent-c15="" class="form-header m-0">System</h5>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div _ngcontent-c15="" class="row">
        <div _ngcontent-c15="" class="form-group col-md-12 p-0">
            <!---->

            <div _ngcontent-c15="" class="form-check radio p-0">
                <input _ngcontent-c15="" class="form-check-input" type="radio">
                    <label _ngcontent-c15="" class="form-check-label">All</label>
                </input>
            </div>

            <div _ngcontent-c15="" class="form-check radio p-0">
                <input _ngcontent-c15="" class="form-check-input" type="radio">
                    <label _ngcontent-c15="" class="form-check-label">None</label>
                </input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the html code of System TAb under with ALL and NONE button is present but there are many other tabs with ALL and none button. Unable to select precise xpath for the radio

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Use this hope it will help: //input[@type='radio']

Comment: Can you paste the tab html tag, I think there should be an attribute that says which tab is active or the class/attribute value might change when you are in an active tab.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the XPath expression below:

```
//div/h5[text()='System']/ancestor::div/div/div/div/input/label[@class='form-check-label' and text()='All']
```

Hope it helps.